# SharpDx Direct2D draw layers on top of each other

Tags: c#, sharpdx, direct2d

I am creating an application using sharpDx Render Control where i want to draw multiple layers in control on top of each other using Direct2d rendertarget and all layers should be visible. But the problem is when i call rendertarget.Clear(Color.Transparent) it clear the screen with black and i can not see other layers. If i do not call Clear method then it does not clear current layer, i am drawing line using mouse move so it is needed to clear layer. I can not draw each layer every time because it can have thousands of objects to draw which can slow down application.
So how to clear layer with transparent background, so i can see other layers at same time? Or is there any other way to do this?

//Sample Code

```
if(!newObject)
DrawAllGeometry(renderTarget, strokeWidth);
else
{
    layer = new Layer(renderTarget, renderTarget.Size);
    var layerParam = new LayerParameters() { ContentBounds = RectangleF.Infinite };
    renderTarget.PushLayer(ref layerParam, layer);
    renderTarget.Clear(Color.Transparent); /* This code makes the screen black. I want this layer transparent, so i can see drawings of DrawAllGeometry() */
    renderTarget.DrawRectangle(new RectangleF(canvasSP.X, -canvasSP.Y, width, height), new SolidColorBrush(renderTarget, Color.Green), strokeWidth * 5);
renderTarget.PopLayer();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some source code, you will likely get more relevant response. I also have some thoughts, but I can't contribute unless I know how your code is executing.

Comment: not sure about 2d but in 3d i rendered non moving objects on a buffer. the buffer is rendered superfast.

Comment: @ Florian Schmidinger- i am drawing more than 200,000 objects and adding new object on new layer because i do not want to draw 200,000 objects again. Is this your case? @Kodaloid- i have updated with sample code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/axefrog/db3a8ce7b00abb13d2d3

Comment: yes thats my case, however i did this with the predecessor of sharpdx for a 3d cad application. I guess you can store off these layers in a list<Layer> and rerender them? In that case a layer is a form of buffer and you just need to respect the order in which they are drawn.

Comment: in the direct2d reference theres a good description about reusing drawings. however it's written in c++... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372260(v=vs.85).aspx#copyingbitmaps